# Rails passing form ID param through form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm new to rails and I am building a todo list app. I am trying to set it up- like Trello so I can output multiple lists and have items under each list. So currently I can create lists, and within each list create list items. Everything is working by taking the player between the different pages but I am trying to combine it all into one page.

Here is a mock up image of what I am trying to get to with each list:

[image: Mock up of Final for Each list]

I mostly have it working. I can create new lists and they automatically appear on the page. If I add items the items appear underneath each list. Here is an image of what I have so far:

[image: Current Progress]

The last piece I am having an issue with is including the ability to create list items right there in the index page from within each list. If you look at the mock up image above there is a text field on the top of the list. I am looking to do the same thing and create a new item for that list.

I am getting this error "NoMethodError in TodoLists#index". I understand why it is erroring out since the index action doesn't know about todo_items but can't figure out how to make it work.

Here is my page index page where I want everything to happen from:

```
               <div class="row wrapper border-bottom white-bg page-heading">

      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <h2>Todo Lists</h2>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
          <li>
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>Todo Lists</a>
          </li>
          <li class="active">
            <strong>Lists</strong>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper wrapper-content  animated fadeInRight">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div id="nestable-menu">
            <%= link_to "Create New List", new_todo_list_path, :class => "btn btn-white btn-sm" %>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <% @todo_lists.each do |todo_list| %>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="ibox">
            <div class="ibox-content">
              <h3><%= link_to todo_list.title, todo_list %>
                -
                <span class="small"><%= todo_list.description %></span>
              </h3>
              <p class="small">
                <i class="fa fa-hand-o-up"></i>
                Drag task between list</p>

              <div class="input-group">

                <%= form_for([@todo_list, @todo_list.todo_items.build]) do |f| %>
                <%= f.text_field :content, placeholder: "New Todo" %>
                <%= f.submit %>
                <% end %>

              </div>

              <ul class="sortable-list connectList agile-list" id="todo">
                <%= todo_list.todo_items.each do |todo_items| %>
                <li class="warning-element" id="task1">

                  <%= todo_items.content %>

                  <div class="agile-detail">

                    <%= link_to "Delete", todo_list_todo_item_path(todo_list, todo_items.id), :class=>"pull-right btn btn-xs btn-danger", method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                    <%= todo_items.created_at.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p') %>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

todo_lists_controller:

```
        class TodoListsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_todo_list, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

      # GET /todo_lists
      # GET /todo_lists.json
      def index
        @todo_lists = TodoList.all
      end

      # GET /todo_lists/1
      # GET /todo_lists/1.json
      def show

      end

      # GET /todo_lists/new
      def new
        @todo_list = TodoList.new
      end

      # GET /todo_lists/1/edit
      def edit
      end

      # POST /todo_lists
      # POST /todo_lists.json
      def create
        @todo_list = TodoList.new(todo_list_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @todo_list.save
            format.html { redirect_to @todo_list, notice: 'Todo list was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @todo_list }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @todo_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # PATCH/PUT /todo_lists/1
      # PATCH/PUT /todo_lists/1.json
      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @todo_list.update(todo_list_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @todo_list, notice: 'Todo list was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @todo_list }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @todo_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # DELETE /todo_lists/1
      # DELETE /todo_lists/1.json
      def destroy
        @todo_list.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Todo list was successfully destroyed.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end

      private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_todo_list
          @todo_list = TodoList.find(params[:id])
        end



        # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
        def todo_list_params
          params.require(:todo_list).permit(:title, :description)
        end
    end
```

todo_items_controller:

```
                class TodoItemsController < ApplicationController
                before_action :set_todo_list
                before_action :set_todo_item, except: [:create]

                def create
                    @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.create(todo_item_params)
                    redirect_to @todo_list
                end



                def destroy
                    if @todo_item.destroy
                        flash[:success] = "Todo List item was deleted."
                    else
                        flash[:error] = "Todo List item could not be deleted."
                    end
                    redirect_to @todo_list
                end

                def complete
                    @todo_item.update_attribute(:completed_at, Time.now)
                    redirect_to @todo_list, notice: "Todo item completed"
                end

                private

                def set_todo_list
                    @todo_list = TodoList.find(params[:todo_list_id])
                end

                def set_todo_item
                    @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.find(params[:id])
                end

                def todo_item_params
                    params[:todo_item].permit(:content)
                end

            end
```

Routes:

```
  resources :todo_lists do
    resources :todo_items do
      member do
          patch :complete
          end
    end
  end
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you emphasize in what you want and what's the error you're getting?, the rails server can give you the most detailed message.

Comment: Updated post to include more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up getting it working! All I had to do in the end was change:

```
<%= form_for([@todo_list, @todo_list.todo_items.build]) do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for([todo_list, TodoItem.new],:remote => true) do |f| %>
```